# How to simply check are all elements in array same?

Tags: python, arrays, element

I have an array with a random elements. How can I check, is all that elements the same or not? Could it be possible with numpy.all ? Thanks

Comment: `len(set(my_array))==1` ?

Comment: Convert it to a set and check it is of size 1. Bah just beaten to it

Comment: I am not agree with marking this post as duplicated because it is related to ```numpy.array``` and not to the ```list```.
And, yes, you could check identity with ```numpy.all(your_array == your_array[0])```

Comment: Another one: `numpy.unique(a).size == 1`

Comment: @TimofeyChernousov Unfortunately, it is such a basic question that I can't find a duplicate for it. I didn't read the question to the end, only the title and tags.

Comment: @TimofeyChernousov: However, the first link I found without fail was the link to the np.all docs, which explicitly document this behaviour. If OP is not willing to put in that much effort to do a little research, this question doesn't deserve to be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `all`:

```
if all(i == a[0] for i in a):   
   #all the elements are the same
   pass
```

You can also use a set:

```
if len(set(a)) == 1:
   #all the elements are the same
   pass
```